# SSH kubernetes pod that is not successfully initialized

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to debug jenkins kubernetes pod which is not initializing. The pod is in initialized state.

Once I run `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep jenkins`

I am getting

`infrastructure   jenkins-fdfc9cf6c-2tvvm   0/1     Init:0/1    0  4m`

I am able to extract the logs using

`kubectl logs jenkins-fdfc9cf6c-2tvvm   -c copy-default-config -n infrastructure`

Is there any way that I can actually SSH to this pod?

I tried `kubectl -n infrastructure exec -it jenkins-fdfc9cf6c-2tvvm /bin/bash`, but I am getting error `error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("jenkins")`.

This is how my container status looks like

```
  containerStatuses:
  - image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    imageID: ""
    lastState: {}
    name: jenkins
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      waiting:
        reason: PodInitializing
```

Any advice how to do this?

Comment: So, You want to debug Init containers. To SSH to the pod you can try : `kubectl exec -it jenkins-fdfc9cf6c-2tvvm -- /bin/bash`

Comment: @Amitkumar that doesn't work. I am getting error `error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("jenkins").` because pod is not initialized yet

Comment: It means your pod is crashing / Jenkins not able to create kubernetes POD. Could you please share the logs ?

Comment: @Boban I think you need to figure out how you set the pod startup command. At this point, 1 logical approach will be to control the command and args for the pod and run that with `sleep infinite` or `cat /dev/null` to keep it running. That should allow you enough time to log in to the pod. Use the command suggested by @Amit kumar

Comment: @Amitkumar

Logs look like this: https://justpaste.it/8h30t

Comment: @Amitkumar I have attached the full log on the above url

Comment: am I right that you have managed to strat the Jenkins?  ( I can see theis question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053913/jenkins-slave-pod-is-offline ). What was the issue?

Comment: The issue was not related to Jenkins configuration. It was related to calico-node pod that was failing and when it fails, it corrupts dns pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't put this as a comment, so I'll post this as an answer and will be editing it.

```
NAMESPACE        NAME                      READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
infrastructure   jenkins-fdfc9cf6c-2tvvm   0/1     Init:0/1    0          4m
```

Try doing `kubectl -n infrastructure get pod jenkins-fdfc9cf6c-2tvvm -o yaml` and checking the Pod's `Phase` and `ContainerStatus` in `status:` section of the YAML. Below is an example from my own test jnkns install.

```
status:
  phase: Running
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: xxxxx
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    name: jenkins
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2020-09-14T10:46:15Z"
```

> I tried `kubectl -n infrastructure exec -it jenkins-fdfc9cf6c-2tvvm /bin/bash`,
> am getting error `error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("jenkins")`.

The `exec` merely executes a `command` in a first container of pod (unless `-c` is specified). So if your container is stuck in some "weird" state, you might be not able to connect to it.

Additionally, one must separate the `command` from the `pod` name by `--` (dash dash) in order to help the `kubectl` parser know that you didn't intend that `/bin/bash` for *it* .

```
$ kubectl exec --help
Usage:
  kubectl exec (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER] [flags] -- COMMAND [args...] [options]
```

So the command should be:
`kubectl -n infrastructure exec -it jenkins-fdfc9cf6c-2tvvm -- /bin/bash`

[Official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) says that

> #### Pod conditions
>
> A Pod has a PodStatus, which has an array of [PodConditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#podcondition-v1-core) through which the Pod has or has not passed:
>
> - `Initialized`: all [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) have started successfully.

That is why I think i'd be interesting to check your deployment file.
In my case I was able running Jenkins with no Init containers. You can find my YAML [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nkolchenko/innovative-solutions/master/64028114-jenkins/jenkins-deployment.yaml).

--- UPD#1
I have played with the yaml you have provided and I'm able to achieve the Pod stuck in a different states :)

```
NAME                           READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-7d9459df65-f4sv8       0/1     Init:0/1   0          1s
```

what is the output of `kubectl describe pod <your jenkins pod>`?  If your pod is stuck in `Init:0/1` then the problem is not with the Jenkins container, but the `InitContainer`

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is how my deployment look like https://justpaste.it/6krou

Comment: I have added a container status response in my question

Comment: Sure, it looks like the issue is with the Init container.  I'm going to run your yaml on my cluster :)

Comment: @Boban , I have added "UPD#1" to the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can run the bash of a pod that is not initializing. But you can start the pod with **sleep** command first and then run `kubectl exec` command to run the bash of that pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ***
    image: ***
    command: ["sleep 3600"]
```

By doing this, the pod won't really run the docker's command, and will initialize correctly. Then you can run `kubectl exec -it -n infrastructure jenkins-fdfc9cf6c-2tvvm  /bin/bash` to access the bash of that pod, then run the original command manually and see what will happen.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `Error: failed to create containerd task: starting container │
process caused: exec: "sleep 3600": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`